# net.js: Cannot read property 'getsockname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, runtime-error

I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getsockname' of undefined
at net.js:1072:23
at Object.6:1 (cluster.js:587:5)
at handleResponse (cluster.js:171:41)
at respond (cluster.js:192:5)
at handleMessage (cluster.js:202:5)
at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:345:11)
```

when trying to run a server program using in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as written in this thread: The problem seems to appear when trying to bind to a privileged port (port numbers below 1024) without having root rights. (assuming it's on Linux OS)

to overcome this problem simply run the program after writing the command:

> sudo su -

which will give you the root rights.